# SQL Server Replication with Temporal Tables

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

After a bit of advise. I have an existing database that extensively uses Temporal tables (i.e. System versioned tables). We are looking at an environment where we have a near to real time replica of production for the development team. This requirement is to get the developers off production and still allow them to do their work.

I now find out that temporal tables are not supported with transnational replication. This is the first time I have had to set up replication so apologies if part of my question is naive.

Looking at a blog, it suggests that it might be possible by;

For the publisher for each temporal table
1. turn off System Versioning.
2. run exec sp_addarticle
3. run exec sp_articlecolumn for all columns except the SysStartTime and SysEndTime columns
4. Turn on System Versioning.

For the Subscriber
1. Build a schema for each temporal table excluding the SysStartTime and SysEndTime columns and removes the FOR PERIOD directive.

Question is - will this work? Or is there more to it or another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do the developers need a 'near real time' copy of the data to do their work? Would a nightly backup be enough?

Comment: The developers are asked to produce analytics on current data, which includes what has happen during the day (current position or current pricing). Also we do find data or calculation issues that relate to the live environment such as live pricing or live risk. Very hard to debug something when you cant replicate the issue.

Comment: If the requirement is strictly read related, have you considered offloading these requirements using log shipping or Always On, both of which work with Temporal Tables?

Comment: Read only would not work. I can see cases where the data would been to be added or altered on the replica.